# How to replace a file at destination with another file at source location using nested for loop in cmd

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

Under one folder, `sourcefiles` for example, I have three `.aar` files:

```
D:\test\sourcefiles\netQ-1.aar
D:\test\sourcefiles\netQ-2.aar
D:\test\sourcefiles\netQ-3.aar
```

I want to replace those `.aar` files at three different locations,

```
D:\fido\netQ-1\netQ-1.aar
D:\fido\netQ-2\netQ-2.aar
D:\fido\netQ-3\netQ-3.aar
```

with the files at `sourcefiles` location, but only if the name of files at destination location matches their names, i.e.

replace `D:\fido\netQ-1\netQ-1.aar` with `D:\test\sourcefiles\netQ-1.aar`
             `D:\fido\netQ-2\netQ-2.aar` with `D:\test\sourcefiles\netQ-2.aar`
             `D:\fido\netQ-3\netQ-2.aar` with `D:\test\sourcefiles\netQ-3.aar`

For this purpose I am trying to use the nested for loop 
command:

```
for /d %a in ('dir /b  D:\test\sourcefiles\*.aar') do FOR /F "usebackq" %b in (`DIR /s /b  D:\fido\\.aar`) do (if /i "%%~xa" equ "%%~xb" (replace the files ))
```

In this `If` condition I am trying to match the file names and then do a replace operation. What is the correct command to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the exact input examples you gave:

from `cmd`

```
@for %i in ("D:\test\sourcefiles\*.aar") do if exist "D:\fido\%~ni\%~nxi" copy "%~i" "D:\fido\%~ni\%~nxi" /Y
```

and from batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("D:\test\sourcefiles\*.aar") do if exist "D:\fido\%%~ni\%%~nxi" copy "%%~i" "D:\fido\%%~ni\%%~nxi" /Y
```

This will only work if the destination folder is really the same as the file name without extension as presented in your example.

**Note** in both cases, remove `echo` only once you are happy with the results `echo`'d to screen. Echo is just a safety measure.

Comment: It does not work. I see the following output command like      if exist "D:\fido\netQ-1\D:\test\sourcefiles\netQ-1.aar" copy "D:\test\sourcefiles\netQ-1.aar" "D:\fido\netQ-1\D:\test\sourcefiles\netQ-1.aar" /Y   But when i checked the dest5ination folder i do not see that the .aar file at destination is modifies . it still remains unreplaced.

Comment: Anyway, I edited the answer to remove the `echo` for you, you can try it as is now.

Comment: Now i am getting error :   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
        0 file(s) copied.

Comment: Thankyou it works now . A minor change in your solution is needed that is instead of `if exist "D:\fido\%~ni\%~nxi" copy "%~i" "D:\fido\%~ni\%~i" /Y ` it should be    `if exist "D:\fido\%~ni\%~nxi" copy "%~i" "D:\fido\%~ni\%~ni.aar" /Y`